# Attribute not found when using python3.7 from terminal but not within ipython

Tags: python, ipython

I have a script in `test.py`, which has the following:

```
import custom_lib

a = custom_lib.mod.value()
```

When I run `python3.7 test.py`, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'custom_lib' has no attribute 'mod'
```

But when I got into `ipython`, and copy and paste `test.py` into it, I get no such error.

The python executable that is used within `ipython` is the same as the one `python3.7` points to. I checked by doing `which python3.7` and in ipython, I did

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

and both point to the same `python3.7`. What could be causing this error?

Comment: Interesting. If `custom_mod` is a placeholder and not the actual name you're using, it's possible there's a naming collision and you're importing a different module with the same name. Try `dir(custom_mod)` to see what the imported module contains, and `custom_mod.__file__` to see which file has been imported as the module.

Comment: Is the `custom_lib` a local module or a third-party module?

Comment: What Python is `ipython` actually using? You may be importing different versions of `custom_lib` in each case.

Comment: @CrazyChucky not sure if I read correctly but `custom_mod` should actually be `sqlalchemy` in this case. I was trying to preserve some anonmity. When I tried `print(dir(sqlalchemy))`, it says `NameError: name 'sqlalchemy' is not defined`

Comment: @PratikThakare I'm actually not sure. I think it's a module that other people at my employer made because when I google'd the name, nothing shows up

Comment: @chepner 3.7.4. I stated this in the OP, or is that not the correct way to check? within `ipython`, I did `import sys` and then `print(sys.executable)` and it pointed to `/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7` and when I did `/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 --version` in terminal it shows `Python 3.7.4`

Comment: As CrazyChucky suggested, is `custom_mod.__file__` the same in both sessions? Or `sys.path`? It's possible you have the same *interpreter* in both, but different search paths that resulting different files being used to define `custom_lib`.

Comment: `ipython` itself is not a Python implementation; it's an interactive wrapper *around* a Python implementation. (Not to be confused with the standard CPython implementation, which provides a rudimentary interactive interpreter itself.)

Comment: @chepner I was a bit confused by CrazyChucky's suggestion. `custom_mod` isn't imported, so when you do `custom_mod.__file__`, it just says it's not defined

Comment: Your reported error suggests *something* was imported; whatever was imported just doesn't have a `mod` attribute. If nothing was imported, you'd get an `ImportError` immediately, not an `AttributeError` after the fact.

Comment: @chepner yes, I imported `custom_lib`, which is supposed to contain the `custom_mod` module. I didn't import `custom_mod` directly

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve]. Are you expecting a submodule to be an attribute of the package that contains it? That's not always the case. `import custom_lib.custom_mod` is not the same thing as `import custom_lib; custom_mod = custom_lib.custom_mod`.

Comment: I misread/mistyped; I meant `custom_lib.__file__`, for instance. Whatever it is you're importing, check where it's coming from, and if it's the same in both places you're trying.